# Google App Invite send all button

Tags: android, button, send, google-app-invites

I am trying to use the Google App invite.
It is working fine and the mail is send & received correctly.

I have just 1 question, is there any way to set "Send all" button or field in App invite, because **currently i have to select every person**, which is quite cumbersome.

is there any way to add "**Send to all**" or "**Select all**" button in Google App invite?

Comment: is there any way to invite all my friends at one go (like Select all or Send all button). Currently i have to individually select every person. i want to send request to all my friends by just one click.

Comment: Haven't noticed this ability in app invites as of yet. You never know if they will add it someday.